# Consequences to manually adding a entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-registry, programsandfeatures

We have an application, lets call it 'App A', that when you run it checks the registry to see if another app, lets call it 'App B', is installed. It does this by searching `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for any entry with a `DisplayName` equal to 'App B'.

Now, App A doesn't actually need App B to run correctly and we've lost the ability to install App B on our systems. So my question is...

Are there any consequences to creating a registry entry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App A` with the appropriate display name? I think this could be accomplished with a *.reg file containing the following...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App 1]
"DisplayName"="App 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on SuperUser, here's the answer...

https://superuser.com/a/1701965/131296